# out of memory workbooks.open (Excel to CSV)

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, vba

I am running the below script to convert .xls files to .csv and getting the error. How can I resolve this?

> out of memory workbooks.open

```
 if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Comment: How big is the xls file?

Comment: its in ?Kbs wit just 1500 rows